# How to calculate the order of elements within these groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm struggling to understand how to calculate the order of specific elements within large groups.
For example if we have $(4,9)$ within $\Bbb Z_{18}\times \Bbb Z_{18}$ (apologies for the lack of use of mathjax).
I know if G is a finite group of order (size) n then, for any $g∈G$, the order (period) of $g$ is a divisor of $n$. Hence knowing the order of $\Bbb Z_{18}\times \Bbb Z_{18}=324=2^2. 9^2$, would this mean that the order of $(4,9)$ in this group must be $2$?

Comment: "apologies for the lack of use of mathjax" 
Mathjax is easy to learn, just read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), it's simple and will make your questions more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Its a product group, so the order is the lcm of the orders of the components.

Here $4$ has order $9$ and $9$ has order $2$ in $\Bbb Z_{18}$.